# Recyclerview isn't quitely visible in CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, layout, fragment, bottomnavigationview

I'm developing an app uses recyclerview for shownig the expenses of the user but I'm facing a problem that the content isn't being seen after scrolling below bottomnavigationview.
This image explain my problem:

[image: My Problem]

and here is my layout:

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/transparent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.AppUiActivity">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
            android:id="@+id/bottom_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/blue_900"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            app:fabCradleMargin="3dp"
            app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="40dp"
            app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:hideOnScroll="false">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:baselineAligned="false">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/categories"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:focusable="true">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="4dp"
                        android:text="@string/categories"
                        android:textSize="11.5sp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/crafty_girls"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        app:drawableTopCompat="@drawable/ic_expense" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/details"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="4dp"
                        android:text="@string/details"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/crafty_girls"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        app:drawableTopCompat="@drawable/ic_details" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:enabled="false"
                    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                    android:gravity="center" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/calculate"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="@string/calculate"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/crafty_girls"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        app:drawableTopCompat="@drawable/ic_calculator" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/total"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="4dp"
                        android:text="@string/total"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/crafty_girls"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        app:drawableTopCompat="@drawable/ic_money" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/add_expenses"
            android:elevation="20dp"
            android:focusable="true"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_bar"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="center"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add"
            tools:ignore="ImageContrastCheck" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

So I need an useful answer please because I have been working on this problem for a week but there is no solution yet.

Comment: Either hide the bottomnav when scrolling down or add a margin to the bottom of recyclerview. Or if all the layout is a coordinator, then try putting the recycler anchor above the bottomnav. Depends on your case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add margin bottom for the recycler view as shown below this will give the list above the `BottomAppBar`

Preview is here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kf809.png

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/transparent">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottom_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/black"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:fabCradleMargin="3dp"
        app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="40dp"
        app:hideOnScroll="false">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/categories"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:gravity="center">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/crafty_girls"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:text="@string/categories"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="11.5sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:drawableTopCompat="@drawable/ic_expense" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/details"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:gravity="center">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/crafty_girls"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:text="@string/details"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:drawableTopCompat="@drawable/ic_details" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:gravity="center" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/calculate"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:gravity="center">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/crafty_girls"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/calculate"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:drawableTopCompat="@drawable/ic_calculator" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/total"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:gravity="center">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/crafty_girls"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:text="@string/total"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:drawableTopCompat="@drawable/ic_money" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/add_expenses"
        android:elevation="20dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="center"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add"
        tools:ignore="ImageContrastCheck" />

    

> *<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>         android:id="@+id/rvList"
>         android:layout_marginBottom="55dp">
>     </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>*

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: just for mention I also added 10dp to the bottom margin, thus the layout will be more beautiful than before

Answer (score 0):

Just add 2 properties to your recyclerview

```
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:paddingBottom="50dp" // adjust this as per requirement
```

when you are at bottom of the list than only these property comes in effect and it will add 50 dp additional padding so that recyclerview have more area at bottom to scroll.

Happy coding!!!

Comment: I tried it already but it made no effect and the result was the same

Answer (score 0):

Instead of guessing on marginBottom on XML best way to perform this by adding bottom padding at runtime after height for the BottomBar is calculated.

In Java

```
bottom_bar.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            bottom_bar.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            recyclerView.setPadding(recyclerView.getPaddingLeft(), 
            recyclerView.getPaddingTop(), recyclerView.getPaddingRight(), 
            recyclerView.getPaddingBottom()+bottom_bar.getHeight());
 }
```

In Kotlin

```
bottom_bar.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {
bottom_bar.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
recyclerView.setPadding(
                recyclerView.paddingLeft,
                recyclerView.paddingTop,
                recyclerView.paddingRight,
                recyclerView.paddingBottom +bottom_bar.height
            )
}
```

You need to also add following attribute to your RecyclerView so that your Recyclerview elements are seen scrolling behind your bottom appbar:

```
android:clipToPadding="false"
```